# I cannot set device owner for my app on device

Tags: android, device-owner

I have been working on setting my apps to device owner through adb shell dpm command but the error came out

```
 Error: Bad admin: ComponentInfo{com.example.oshao.autolock/com.example.oshao.
```

autolock.AdminReceiver}

Here is my activity and manifests

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DevicePolicyManager mDpm;
private boolean isKioskModeEnabled = false;
private Button btnEnabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnEnabled = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnable);
    btnEnabled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            enableKioskMode(!isKioskModeEnabled);
        }
    });

    ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This ap is not a device admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
        mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName()});
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This app is not the device owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void enableKioskMode(boolean enabled) {

    if (enabled) {

        if (mDpm.isLockTaskPermitted(this.getPackageName())) {

            startLockTask();
            isKioskModeEnabled = true;
            btnEnabled.setText("Exit Kiosk Mode");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kiosk Mode is not permitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {

        stopLockTask();
        isKioskModeEnabled = false;
        btnEnabled.setText("Enter Kiosk Mode");

    }

}
}
```

the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.oshao.autolock.AdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

I am not sure why the error is still out there, is that because one device could only have single app that be set device owner?
Another question is that the adb command could be implemented on a device without account and connect to pc in order to input command in terminal. Can I do it by code in app under the circumstances the device is not rooted because I have several devices and it is hard to set them one by one, Thanks

Comment: There can be more than one app as DeviceAdmin. Check this link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: try adding a description for the AdminReceiver in the manifest like so : `<receiver
        android:name="com.example.oshao.autolock.AdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
android:description="@string/device_admin_description">`

Comment: @AkhilSoman  
I do not think adding a xml file in description would solve the adb error, I have tried this,Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you extended the DeviceAdminReceiver class like the [api guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) specifies?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the bad admin error when I followed this tutorial: http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/

I was missing the `src/main/res/xml/device_admin.xml` file, which only contained:

`<device-admin>
</device-admin>`

Comment: I have already notice the missing file and I add it into xml... Still not working, Any other modification you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You must first set active admin after that set device owner and be careful your package name must be correct.